# How can I create a temporary table from a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view, temp-tables

I have an SQL statement as follows:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE UserRolesTemp LIKE UserRoles
```

However the `UserRoles` table was recently changed to a view and now I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1347 'assets_gca.UserRoles' is not BASE TABLE
```

Is there a way I can still create this temporary table using the view structure, or do I need to write out the table myself in the SQL?

Comment: Do you need to preserve column attributes and indexes defined in the original table?. Maybe you can use [13.1.18.5 CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html). `LIKE works only for base tables, not for views.`, see [13.1.18.4 CREATE TABLE ... LIKE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-like.html).

Comment: This seems to be a suitable workaround, thanks. Does that mean I can't run any query with a `LIKE` clause on a view, or is that just for `CREATE TABLE LIKE`?

Comment: You can use `LIKE` in other view contexts, for example, `... WHERE \`value\` LIKE 'a%';`. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2p9YQMivauuHncggNKgVYg/0).